# How differentiate `0` from `False` In python

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I'm trying to configure the following `if else` :

Basically `0` **is equals** to `False` in Python...

I would like to understand why this happens and how I can workaround in this case :

```
x=0

if x==False:
   print "x == False" #always prints this line
elif x == 0:
   print "x == 0"
```

Appreciate the help:

**EDIT:**

> already tried `x = int(0)`

Comment: I guess you want to use `False` to have some special meaning such as failure as opposed to a number. I suggest using `None` instead.

Comment: @AlexHall that's exactly what I meant! Thanks!!! Sorry for the noobness

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `x is False` to check whether `x` is exactly `False`.

I doubt you really need it though.

Comment: yep! solved my problem! thanks!!! and yes, I won't need it I will use none instead of 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
if x is False:
   print "x is False" #always prints this line
elif x is 0:
   print "x is 0"
```

Because `0 == False` but `0 is not False`.

Comment: yep! solved my problem! thanks!!!

Comment: do not compare numbers with `is`! `x = 10**3; y = 10**3; x is y` => `False`